# Автоперевод текста в латиницу

Tags: php

Есть 2 текстовых поля. Как сделать, чтобы при вводе текста в первое поле символы во второй дублировались и автоматически становились латиницей?

Как тут: https://pp.vk.me/c620518/v620518614/1431c/dxomk-Lk4b4.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается не на сервере на php, а на стороне клиента, например, на javascript.
Создаешь массив, где каждой букве русского алфавита соотносишь букву английского. При вводе  текста в строку берешь из этого массива элемент, соответствующий русской введенной букве, и соответствующую английскую букву подставляешь во вторую строку.

Вот готовое решение http://ajaxs.ru/lesson/js/137-transliteracija_stroki_na_javascript.html

Comment: Огромное спасибо